# Can I declare mutually recursive functions with attributes in F#?

Tags: f#

So; this code compiles fine (although I wouldn't advise running it...):

```
let rec firstFunc () =
  secondFunc ()

and secondFunc () =
  firstFunc ()
```

But! This code does not:

```
let rec firstFunc () =
  secondFunc ()

[<CompiledName "SecondFunc">]
and secondFunc () =
  firstFunc ()
```

Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the attribute after the `and` and it seems to compile fine.

```
let rec firstFunc () =
  secondFunc ()

and [<CompiledName "SecondFunc">] secondFunc () =
  firstFunc ()
```

Comment: Thanks, yes - Vesa just pointed out the same on twitter https://twitter.com/VesaKarvonen/status/770247570593574912

Comment: It's a pity as I prefer the other format aesthetically. Ah, well. Such is life.

Comment: See my answer below for another way to format this (I edited it). Leave the checkmark on Pierre Irrmann's answer, though, since I wouldn't have known about it without his answer. He deserves the credit for this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the CompiledName attribute on one function but not both, you could do:

```
[<CompiledName "SecondFunc">]
let rec secondFunc () =
  firstFunc ()

and firstFunc () =
  secondFunc ()
```

<del>But if you need it on both, I haven't found a solution yet.</del>

To follow up on Pierre Irrmann's answer, you could also do the following if you like seeing your attributes on a separate line:

```
let rec firstFunc () =
    secondFunc ()

and [<CompiledName("SecondFunction")>]
    secondFunc () =
        firstFunc ()
```

or even:

```
let rec firstFunc () =
    secondFunc ()

and
    [<CompiledName("SecondFunction")>]
    secondFunc () =
        firstFunc ()
```

The only requirement is that the `secondFunc ()` declaration, and its attribute, must be indented at least one space. So even this would work:

```
let rec firstFunc () =
    secondFunc ()

and
 [<CompiledName("SecondFunction")>]
 secondFunc () =
     firstFunc ()
```

I don't particularly recommend that last option, though. I've tested it and it works, but it looks ugly. Better to indent a whole indentation level (four or two spaces, whatever you're using) than to get "cute" and indent just a single space in a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've managed to come up with so far is:

```
let rec firstFunc () =
  fakeSecondFunc ()

and fakeSecondFunc () =
  firstFunc ()

[<CompiledName "SecondFunc">]
let secondFunc () =
  fakeSecondFunc ()
```